# Serializing object using json.net using lambda selector

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have the following code

```
class MyJSONSerializableClass
{        
    [JsonProperty("index")]
    public int Index { get; set; };

    [JsonIgnore]
    public long Id { get; set; };
}

var collection = new List<MyJSONSerializableClass>()
{
    new MyJSONSerializableClass() 
    {
        Index = 10,
        Id = 1000
    }
};

string jsonOutput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(collection);
```

jsonOutput would be

```
[{ index: 10 }]
```

I would like jsonOutput to be

```
[ 10 ]
```

Is there any class attribute I can apply to MyJSONSerializableClass that would tell JSON.NET to emit only the property Index, instead of the entire object?

Something along the lines of

```
[JsonOutput(f => f.Index)]
class MyJSONSerializableClass
{
   ...
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the attributes, but alternatively, you could try

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(collection.Select(o => o.Index)).
```

As per [documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/), all IEnumerable's will be arrays.